# Actions.refresh navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I use react-native-router-flux for my navigation. I have a problem with Actions.refresh(). When I execute it nothing happen ...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Picture extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Constructor picture")
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('Will mount picture')
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        console.log("Will Update picture")
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("will Unmont picture")
    }
    render() {
        console.log("render Picture")
        return (
            <Button title='refresh' onPress={() => Actions.refresh()}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Someone know how use it ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Pass Props as per You Need . you Can Find Props Details on nodel_modules/react-native-router-flux/src/navigationStore.js

```
_helloFunction =  () => {
  alert("Hello");
}

componentDidMount() {
    Actions.refresh({
    right: () => alert("Right"),
    left: this._helloFunction
    });
}
```